# Is there an official CLI for Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

Is there an official command line interface (CLI) for interacting with the Foundry APIs provided by Palantir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there currently is none. There used to be one, but it's been deprecated.

There has been some internal interest to revive something like this, but until such a time that something like that materializes for real, the best way to interact with foundry is to use the REST APIs from something like `curl` or python with `requests`.

For more minor automation work, the most straightforward thing to do is likely to observe and replicate the network calls being made in your browsers debug tools "network" tab.

For more substantial efforts, the "documentation" section in your foundry instance provides you a full documentation for many of the services APIs, and also allows you to copy the [conjure](https://github.com/palantir/conjure) definition (similar to OpenAPI/swagger) for a given API. From this it is then possible to construct a rust, python, go, java or typescript client, which makes it easier to interact with the service, if you have more complex needs.

Long-term I hope we can make these conjure clients publicly available (and publish them to NPM/maven/etc), as that would make things a lot simpler. As always, if you find there's any documentation lacking, or you are having trouble with constructing a conjure client or similar, talk to your palantir PoC, and they might be able to just provide you with what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonathan! I am indeed maintaining my own, unofficial python foundry rest client and would appreciate an official solution.